# What is the >< icon in the left of the VS Code status bar?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

What is the green `><` icon in the left corner of my VS Code status bar? What caused it to show up?

[image: green >< icon in status bar]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `><` icon in the status bar is the Remote Window Indicator. It will only show up if you have the [VS Code Remote Development](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview) extensions installed

When working in a remote workspace, the Remote Window Indicator expands to show information about the remote you are connected to:

[image: The remote icon indicator when in a dev container]

You can click on the Remote Window Indicator to see a list of remote commands. If you are not connected to a remote workspace, these commands will help you setup a connection. If you are connected, the commands will help you manage the remote workspace.

[image: The remote commands]